# discord.js turning on and off setInterval()

Tags: discord.js

Ok so I'm trying to make a toggle able setInterval() function, but it's not working. I feel as I've tried every possibility for this, but no outcome has worked. right now my code is:

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    const PingChannel = bot.channels.cache.get('706662769570742333')
    const startPing = bot.setInterval(function(){PingChannel.send('<@&707036166486097990>')}, 1500)
    if(msg.author.id === bot.user.id || msg.author.id === '706969260249055304'){
    return;
    }
    else if(msg.content === "?start" && msg.member.roles.cache.has('706701034449403987')){
    msg.delete()
    startPing
    }
    else if(msg.content === "?stop" && msg.member.roles.cache.has('706701034449403987')){
    clearInterval(startPing)
    msg.reply('pinging successfully stopped!')
    }
});
```

the '?start' works, but the interval is a little laggy. It's not sending a message every 1.5 seconds like it should but instead, it sends around 3-5 messages every like 4 seconds. and the stop function just completely doesn't work.

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    const PingChannel = bot.channels.cache.get('706662769570742333')
    if(msg.author.id === bot.user.id || msg.author.id === '706969260249055304'){
    return;
    }
    else if(msg.content === "?start" && msg.member.roles.cache.has('706701034449403987')){
    msg.delete()
    setInterval(function(){
    PingChannel.send('<@&707036166486097990>')
    }, 1500)
    }
    else if(msg.content === "?stop" && msg.member.roles.cache.has('706701034449403987')){
    clearInterval()
    msg.reply('pinging successfully stopped!')
    }
});
```

i've also tried this, and i like to stick to this as the interval doesn't lag and it sends a message every 1.5 seconds like it should. but of course, the '?stop' doesn't work at all.

any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain why your interval isn't getting stopped. [Reference for what I'm about to say](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp). In your first chunk of code, you assigned your interval inside the function. Later when you did `clearInterval(startPing)`, the variable startPing no longer existed because it was destroyed when your message function finished so you couldn't clear the interval. In your second chunk of code, you didn't provide anything to clearInterval so it couldn't clear what you wanted to clear.

The solution to this is to create a variable outside of the function.

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
  PingChannel = bot.channels.cache.get('706662769570742333');
});

var PingChannel;
var myinterval;

bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.author.id === bot.user.id || msg.author.id === '706969260249055304'){
      return;
    }
    else if(msg.content === "?start" && msg.member.roles.cache.has('706701034449403987')){
      msg.delete()
      myinterval = setInterval(function(){
        PingChannel.send('<@&707036166486097990>')
      }, 1500)
    }
    else if(msg.content === "?stop" && msg.member.roles.cache.has('706701034449403987')){
      clearInterval(myinterval)
      msg.reply('pinging successfully stopped!')
    }
});
```

Hope it works

Comment: I added your suggestion into my code and when I run it, I get this error: https://gyazo.com/f3043aa42f6321b9342bdc02cb32dded
I'm not too sure what this means, any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Oh I noticed now it needs to be a var, my bad. I changed it and now the code works fine! Thank you!

Comment: my bad. yeah it needs to be `var` or `let`. `const` wouldn't work because it prevents you from reassigning something to the variable.